# Calendar always displayed like event list & cannot change to other view

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

In Outlook 2013 on a new computer I have problem with calendar. Whenever I choose calendar it gets displayed not in a week or month view but only as event list like this.

[image]

I have to change to another Calendar folder (folder in another OST file) and back to the default Calendar folder to enable Month or Week view.

After I switch back to e-mails and back again to calendar, it is again in event list view. I do not see this ribbon there, this ribbon is available under other calendar folders only (Archive, Online archive etc.):

[image]

How to fix it to make the default calendar display in month view, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I had to do was to change the view of the Calendar folder from List to Calendar.

[image]